# setAttribute not working as expected in HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to set filter in webpage before downloading.

Code snipped

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10 * 1000);
HtmlElement fromDate = pageAnchorReport.getFirstByXPath("//div[contains(@class,'x-grid3-col-FilterFieldFilterFrom')]"); 
fromDate.setAttribute("Value(s)/From","01/05/2018");
System.out.println("1");

HtmlElement toDate = pageAnchorReport.getFirstByXPath("//div[contains(@class,'x-grid3-col-FilterFieldFilterTo')]"); 
toDate.setAttribute("To","15/10/2018");
System.out.println("2");
```

But its taking dates only which are mentioned in website not from the code am passing.

Any suggestions please. Am I missing anything ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Squeez, please provide more detailed information.

Comment: @Beezer, tell me ..I'll share..!

Comment: @Beezer, check this image where date fields are mentioned. So when am running  my code its not taking dates from my code. Its working on dates mentioned in website only. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBx1E.png

Comment: Have you stepped through your code to check that the Xpath is working correctly?

Comment: @Beezer, Its mentioned in Image url,please check...If its wrong please share

Comment: I would like to help further, but those are my suggestions...which is to step through the unit test.

Answer (score 0):

According to your posted picture the date value set as a text, not in any attribute

So, you could try
`fromDate.setTextContent("01/05/2018");` and `toDate.setTextContent("15/10/2018");` instead of setting attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are trying to set the value for the element attribute that does not exist.
 (`'To'`, `'Value(s)/From'` These are not attributes, these are just inner text contents of that node.)

To set an element attribute, you need to pass a valid attribute name (for example for an `input` element you have to pass `'value'` attribute as `elementObj.setAttribute("value", "YOUR_VALUE")`).

In your case, replace your code with this:

```
h.setNodeValue("YOUR_VALUE");
// or
h.setTextContent("YOUR_VALUE");
```